# Firestore: get an array of objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get an array of objects from Firestore.  I tried something like below but I am getting undefined when I tried to log comments[0].comment

```
  let comments = [{}]
  try {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('comments')
      .where('ytid', '==', id)
    const commentSnapshot = await ref.get()
    let comments = commentSnapshot
    console.log('comment snapshot')
    console.log(comments[0].comment) //undefined
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to get an array. You're currently getting a collection, but not correctly addressing the documents inside. You may want to look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: @jnpdx you are right, need to somehow create an object and push the object into the array of objects.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of how your Firestore doc looks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) which contains the [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) of each document that has matched your query.

```
const commentsSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('comments').where('ytid', '==', id).get()
```

The array of object is a field in your document. You cannot get a single field from a document. You need to fetch the document and then access that field hence you make that query above first.

Now `commentsSnapshot.docs` is an array of DocumentSnapshots. Now if you know there is only one matching document you can access it's data like this:

```
const firstCommentData = commentsSnapshot.docs[0].data()
//Access a specific field
const anyField = firstCommentData.anyField
```

In case your QuerySnapshot has multiple documents, you can loop thought the docs as it is an array.

```
//commentsSnapshot.forEach(...) works as well
commentsSnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out.  I did it like below and it works.

```
  let comments = []
  try {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('comments')
      .where('ytid', '==', id)
    const commentSnapshot = await ref.get()
    commentSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      var obj = {}
      obj['comment'] = doc.data().comment
      obj['createdat'] = doc.data().createdat
      obj['username'] = doc.data().username
      obj['name'] = doc.data().name
      obj['photourl'] = doc.data().photourl

      comments.push(obj)
    })
```